# Tkinter resize a rectange on Canvas using mouse

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a simple GUI image labeler tool in Tkinter for my research project. Currently, I have working code that can load images from the directory and allows me to draw multiple bounding boxes. I want to modify the code such that I can resize the rectangle BB using a mouse when I click on it. I have searched online and couldn't find any resources to do that. Can someone help me understand how to do that?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import glob
import random

# colors for the bboxes
COLORS = ['red', 'blue','pink', 'cyan', 'green', 'black']
# image sizes for the examples
SIZE = 256, 256

class LabelTool():
    def __init__(self, master):
        # set up the main frame
        self.parent = master
        self.parent.title("LabelTool")
        self.frame = Frame(self.parent)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.parent.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)

        # initialize global state
        self.imageDir = ''
        self.imageList= []
        self.egDir = ''
        self.egList = []
        self.outDir = ''
        self.cur = 0
        self.total = 0
        self.category = 0
        self.imagename = ''
        self.labelfilename = ''
        self.tkimg = None
        self.currentLabelclass = ''
        self.cla_can_temp = []
        self.classcandidate_filename = 'class.txt'

        # initialize mouse state
        self.STATE = {}
        self.STATE['click'] = 0
        self.STATE['x'], self.STATE['y'] = 0, 0

        # reference to bbox
        self.bboxIdList = []
        self.bboxId = None
        self.bboxList = []
        self.hl = None
        self.vl = None

        
        self.srcDirBtn = Button(self.frame, text="Image input folder", command=self.selectSrcDir)
        self.srcDirBtn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        # input image dir entry
        self.svSourcePath = StringVar()
        self.entrySrc = Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.svSourcePath)
        self.entrySrc.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W+E)
        self.svSourcePath.set(os.getcwd())

        # load button
        self.ldBtn = Button(self.frame, text="Load Dir", command=self.loadDir)
        self.ldBtn.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady=2, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        # label file save dir button
        self.desDirBtn = Button(self.frame, text="Label output folder", command=self.selectDesDir)
        self.desDirBtn.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # label file save dir entry
        self.svDestinationPath = StringVar()
        self.entryDes = Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.svDestinationPath)
        self.entryDes.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W+E)
        self.svDestinationPath.set(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Labels"))
        
        # main panel for labeling
        self.mainPanel = Canvas(self.frame, cursor='tcross')
        self.mainPanel.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouseClick)
        self.mainPanel.bind("<Motion>", self.mouseMove)
        self.mainPanel.grid(row = 2, column = 1, rowspan = 4, sticky = W+N)

        

        # showing bbox info & delete bbox
        self.lb1 = Label(self.frame, text = 'Bounding boxes:')
        self.lb1.grid(row = 3, column = 2,  sticky = W+N)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.frame, width = 22, height = 12)
        self.listbox.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = N+S)
        # control panel for image navigation
        self.ctrPanel = Frame(self.frame)
        self.ctrPanel.grid(row = 6, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W+E)
        self.progLabel = Label(self.ctrPanel, text = "Progress:     /    ")
        self.progLabel.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5)
        self.tmpLabel = Label(self.ctrPanel, text = "Go to Image No.")
        self.tmpLabel.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5)
        self.idxEntry = Entry(self.ctrPanel, width = 5)
        self.idxEntry.pack(side = LEFT)
        
        

        # display mouse position
        self.disp = Label(self.ctrPanel, text='')
        self.disp.pack(side = RIGHT)

        self.frame.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(4, weight = 1)

    def selectSrcDir(self):
        path = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select image source folder", initialdir=self.svSourcePath.get())
        self.svSourcePath.set(path)
        return

    def selectDesDir(self):
        path = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select label output folder", initialdir=self.svDestinationPath.get())
        self.svDestinationPath.set(path)
        return

    def loadDir(self):
        self.parent.focus()
        # get image list
        #self.imageDir = os.path.join(r'./Images', '%03d' %(self.category))
        self.imageDir = self.svSourcePath.get()
        if not os.path.isdir(self.imageDir):
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", message = "The specified dir doesn't exist!")
            return

        extlist = ["*.JPEG", "*.jpeg", "*JPG", "*.jpg", "*.PNG", "*.png", "*.BMP", "*.bmp"]
        for e in extlist:
            filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.imageDir, e))
            self.imageList.extend(filelist)
        #self.imageList = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.imageDir, '*.JPEG'))
        if len(self.imageList) == 0:
            print('No .JPEG images found in the specified dir!')
            return

        # default to the 1st image in the collection
        self.cur = 1
        self.total = len(self.imageList)

        # set up output dir
        #self.outDir = os.path.join(r'./Labels', '%03d' %(self.category))
        self.outDir = self.svDestinationPath.get()
        if not os.path.exists(self.outDir):
            os.mkdir(self.outDir)

        

        self.loadImage()
        print('%d images loaded from %s' %(self.total, self.imageDir))

    def loadImage(self):
        # load image
        imagepath = self.imageList[self.cur - 1]
        self.img = Image.open(imagepath)
        size = self.img.size
        self.factor = max(size[0]/1000, size[1]/1000., 1.)
        self.img = self.img.resize((int(size[0]/self.factor), int(size[1]/self.factor)))
        self.tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.mainPanel.config(width = max(self.tkimg.width(), 400), height = max(self.tkimg.height(), 400))
        self.mainPanel.create_image(0, 0, image = self.tkimg, anchor=NW)
        self.progLabel.config(text = "%04d/%04d" %(self.cur, self.total))

        # load labels
        self.clearBBox()
        #self.imagename = os.path.split(imagepath)[-1].split('.')[0]
        fullfilename = os.path.basename(imagepath)
        self.imagename, _ = os.path.splitext(fullfilename)
        labelname = self.imagename + '.txt'
        self.labelfilename = os.path.join(self.outDir, labelname)
        bbox_cnt = 0
        if os.path.exists(self.labelfilename):
            with open(self.labelfilename) as f:
                for (i, line) in enumerate(f):
                    if i == 0:
                        bbox_cnt = int(line.strip())
                        continue
                    #tmp = [int(t.strip()) for t in line.split()]
                    tmp = line.split()
                    tmp[0] = int(int(tmp[0])/self.factor)
                    tmp[1] = int(int(tmp[1])/self.factor)
                    tmp[2] = int(int(tmp[2])/self.factor)
                    tmp[3] = int(int(tmp[3])/self.factor)
                    self.bboxList.append(tuple(tmp))
                    color_index = (len(self.bboxList)-1) % len(COLORS)
                    tmpId = self.mainPanel.create_rectangle(tmp[0], tmp[1], \
                                                            tmp[2], tmp[3], \
                                                            width = 2, \
                                                            outline = COLORS[color_index])
                                                            #outline = COLORS[(len(self.bboxList)-1) % len(COLORS)])
                    self.bboxIdList.append(tmpId)
                    self.listbox.insert(END, '%s : (%d, %d) -> (%d, %d)' %(tmp[4], tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3]))
                    self.listbox.itemconfig(len(self.bboxIdList) - 1, fg = COLORS[color_index])
                    #self.listbox.itemconfig(len(self.bboxIdList) - 1, fg = COLORS[(len(self.bboxIdList) - 1) % len(COLORS)])



    def mouseClick(self, event):
        if self.STATE['click'] == 0:
            self.STATE['x'], self.STATE['y'] = event.x, event.y
        else:
            x1, x2 = min(self.STATE['x'], event.x), max(self.STATE['x'], event.x)
            y1, y2 = min(self.STATE['y'], event.y), max(self.STATE['y'], event.y)
            self.bboxList.append((x1, y1, x2, y2, self.currentLabelclass))
            self.bboxIdList.append(self.bboxId)
            self.bboxId = None
            self.listbox.insert(END, '%s : (%d, %d) -> (%d, %d)' %(self.currentLabelclass, x1, y1, x2, y2))
            self.listbox.itemconfig(len(self.bboxIdList) - 1, fg = COLORS[(len(self.bboxIdList) - 1) % len(COLORS)])
        self.STATE['click'] = 1 - self.STATE['click']

    def mouseMove(self, event):
        self.disp.config(text = 'x: %d, y: %d' %(event.x, event.y))
        if self.tkimg:
            if self.hl:
                self.mainPanel.delete(self.hl)
            self.hl = self.mainPanel.create_line(0, event.y, self.tkimg.width(), event.y, width = 2)
            if self.vl:
                self.mainPanel.delete(self.vl)
            self.vl = self.mainPanel.create_line(event.x, 0, event.x, self.tkimg.height(), width = 2)
        if 1 == self.STATE['click']:
            if self.bboxId:
                self.mainPanel.delete(self.bboxId)
            COLOR_INDEX = len(self.bboxIdList) % len(COLORS)
            self.bboxId = self.mainPanel.create_rectangle(self.STATE['x'], self.STATE['y'], \
                                                            event.x, event.y, \
                                                            width = 2, \
                                                            outline = COLORS[len(self.bboxList) % len(COLORS)])

    

    def setClass(self):
        self.currentLabelclass = self.classcandidate.get()
        print('set label class to : %s' % self.currentLabelclass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    tool = LabelTool(root)
    root.resizable(width =  True, height = True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not interested in sorting through 300 lines of your code, but as a starting point I'll note that you can use `Canvas.tag_bind` to bind a function to a canvas item like a rectangle, so you can just make a resize function from that.

Comment: Please reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If your question is about resizing a rectangle, all we need is a canvas with a single rectangle on it, and enough other code to run and show us what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have modified the code down to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The code is far from minimal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one that is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's hardly "minimal" ... it's still over 200 lines long. I don't want to sort through it but I'll make a minimal example to show you how to bind to a canvas item:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

class DrawShapes(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        image = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, 400, 300, width=5, fill='green')
        self.tag_bind(image, '<Button-1>', self.on_click)
        self.tag_bind(image, '<Button1-Motion>', self.on_motion)

    def on_click(self, event):
        """fires when user clicks on the background ... creates a new rectangle"""
        self.start = event.x, event.y
        self.current = self.create_rectangle(*self.start, *self.start, width=5)
        self.tag_bind(self.current, '<Button-1>', partial(self.on_click_rectangle, self.current))
        self.tag_bind(self.current, '<Button1-Motion>', self.on_motion)

    def on_click_rectangle(self, tag, event):
        """fires when the user clicks on a rectangle ... edits the clicked on rectange"""
        self.current = tag
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.coords(tag)
        if abs(event.x-x1) < abs(event.x-x2):
            # opposing side was grabbed; swap the anchor and mobile side
            x1, x2 = x2, x1
        if abs(event.y-y1) < abs(event.y-y2):
            y1, y2 = y2, y1
        self.start = x1, y1

    def on_motion(self, event):
        """fires when the user drags the mouse ... resizes currently active rectangle"""
        self.coords(self.current, *self.start, event.x, event.y)

def main():
    c = DrawShapes()
    c.pack()
    c.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Smart use of `functools.partial`. Why do you need a background rectangle covering the entire canvas?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I assumed from OPs question that they are trying to annotate an image. The background rectangle is just a standin for the image.

Comment: Ahhh, of course, that makes sense; thank you!