# tkinter delete circle using mouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to delete mouse-created circles with the right button. I also want to delete each circle separately. I modify my code with this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65174542/13560126) to create circles but however when I try to delete each of them, I always getting an error. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from functools import partial

class DrawCircles(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        image = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300, width=4, fill='grey')
        self.tag_bind(image, '<Button-1>', self.on_click)
        self.tag_bind(image, '<Button1-Motion>', self.on_motion)
        self.tag_bind(image, '<Button-3>', self.delete)

    def delete(self):
        super().delete('all')

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.start = event.x, event.y
        self.current = self.create_oval(*self.start, *self.start, width=5,outline='yellow')
        self.tag_bind(self.current, '<Button-1>', partial(self.on_click_circle, self.current))
        self.tag_bind(self.current, '<Button1-Motion>', self.on_motion)


    def on_click_circle(self, tag, event):
        self.current = tag
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.coords(tag)
        if abs(event.x-x1) < abs(event.x-x2):
            x1, x2 = x2, x1
        if abs(event.y-y1) < abs(event.y-y2):
            y1, y2 = y2, y1
        self.start = x1, y1
        print(x1,y1,x2,y2)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        self.coords(self.current, *self.start, event.x, event.y)

    def on_move(self,event):
        component = self.current
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.coords(component)
        locx, locy = component.winfo_x(), component.winfo_y()
        mx ,my =component.winfo_width(),component.winfo_height()
        xpos=(locx+event.x)-int(mx/2)
        ypos=(locy+event.y)-int(my/2)
    
        if xpos>=0 and ypos>=0: 
            component.place(x=xpos,y=ypos)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = DrawCircles()
    main.pack()
    main.mainloop()
```

Error:

> delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: ```def delete(self,*args):```, check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `delete()` function, gets called on pressing 'Button-3', i.e., it is triggered as an event to the canvas, so it takes in an extra parameter(like `e` or `event` or whatever), which you are not passing.

So EITHER pass `e` during function call OR define `e` as a parameter during function definition.

```
self.tag_bind(image, '<Button-3>', lambda e: self.delete()) # Same as event or any_var_name_at_all
```

Or

```
def delete(self,event): # Same as e or any_var_name_at_all
    super().delete('all')
```